# Python script to append data in one csv to another csv after compare

Tags: python, csv, append

I have a script which compares 2 csv files and outputs the data to a new CSV file. 
I am looking for help to be able to append the data in the new output file to the allhistory file in thee same code. Anyone suggest what to use?

```
import csv

with open('allhistory.csv', 'r') as t1, open('filewithnewdata.csv', 'r') as t2:
    fileone = t1.readlines()
    filetwo = t2.readlines()

with open('update.csv', 'w') as outFile:
    for line in filetwo:
        if line not in fileone:
            outFile.write(line)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could keep a list of the lines that you write to `update.csv` and then write the contents of `fileone` followed by the updates, overwriting the existing file. For example:

```
with open('allhistory.csv', 'r') as t1, open('filewithnewdata.csv', 'r') as t2:
    fileone = t1.readlines()
    filetwo = t2.readlines()

matches = []

with open('update.csv', 'w') as outFile:
    for line in filetwo:
        if line not in fileone:
            matches.append(line)
            outFile.write(line)    

with open('allhistory.csv', 'w') as outFile:
    outFile.write(''.join(fileone).strip() + '\n' + ''.join(matches))
```

Note, you are just comparing whole lines in the file, you are not currently using `csv` to split each line into values.

Comment: Thanks very much... that works but there is an empty line in between the original data and new data added. Is there away to not have any blank lines in between?

Comment: You can add `strip()` to ensure there is only one newline.